# select count(*) as part of larger select query

Tags: sql-server, select, join, count

I'm using two queries:

```
select * from ControlPoints where LineGroup = 123001
select count(*) from BitAssignments where LineGroup = 123001
```

to determine if I need to update the BitAssignments table. Can I combine these two queries somehow?

These two tables are populated from an external source, and the idea is 1) to see if any members of ControlPoints are missing, and 2) if they are present, to see if all the BitAssignments are in the table.

Schema are as follows:

```
ControlPoints table
   LineGroup     int (primary key)
   Name          string
   NumControls   int
   NumInd        int

BitAssignments table
   LineGroup     int
   BitPosition   int
   Mnemonic      string
```

For a given ControlPoint, there will be only one record in the ControlPoints table, but there may be hundreds of rows of Bit data in the BitAssignments table.

I need a query that tells me if new control points in the external data have been added (or deleted), or if new bit assignments to an existing control point have been added/removed from external data. The alternative is rebuilding both tables from scratch, but this process takes over 12 hours to complete (about 300,000 records in BitAssignments).

Something along the lines of:

```
select a.LineGroup b.select count(Mnemonic) from ControlPoints a, BitAssignments b where a.LineGroup=123001
```

which, of course, does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 steps:

1. JOIN tables
2. Add GROUP BY clause since you are using COUNT aggregation function

After those 2 steps your query would look like this:

```
SELECT cp.LineGroup, cp.Name, cp.NumControls, cp.NumInd, COUNT(ba.Mnemonic) BitAssignmentsCnt
FROM ControlPoints cp LEFT JOIN BitAssignments ba ON cp.LineGroup=ba.LineGroup
GROUP BY cp.LineGroup, cp.Name, cp.NumControls, cp.NumInd, ba.LineGroup
```

You would use [LEFT JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) if you would want to display all ControlPoints no matter if they have any BitAssignments or not. If you are not interested in BitAssignmentsCnt=0 you can use [INNER JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) instead of LEFT JOIN.

[GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) needs to specify all columns you are using in query (either in select or in JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want a simple group by, or a count with a partition.

```
select
    cp.*
    ,count(b.Mnemonic) over (partition by cp.LineGroup or by NumInd)
from
    ControlPoints cp
left join
    BitAssignments b on b.LineGroup = cp.LineGroup
```

**OR PERHAPS...**

```
select
    cp.*
    ,count(b.Mnemonic) 
from
    ControlPoints cp
left join
    BitAssignments b on b.LineGroup = cp.LineGroup 
group by
    cp.LineGroup
    ,cp.Name
    ,cp.NumControls
    ,cp.NumInd
```